# Search on text file via multiple variables

Tags: java, text-files

Basically I want to search my text file with multiple variables.

My code so far:

```
    public boolean searchStudent() throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("src", "inware", "users.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(p);
        boolean i = false;

        String search =search_field.getText();
        String[] search1 = search.split("[,]");

        String format = "%-10s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s\n";
        rsl.append(String.format(format,"Όνομα:","Επίθετο:","Φύλο:","Ημ. Γέννησης:","Τάξη:","Όνομα Κηδεμόνα:","Επώνυμο Κηδεμόνα:","Τηλ. Κηδεμόνα:","Συν. Απουσίες:","Ημ. Τελ. Απουσίας:","Αρ. Τελ. Απουσίας:","Μάθημα 1:","Μάθημα 2:","Μάθημα 3:","Μάθημα 4:","Μάθημα 5:","Μάθημα 6:","Μ.Ο.:"));
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split("[,]");

            if (line.contains(search1[0])&& line.contains(search1[1])) { //What i must put here???
                    rsl.append(String.format(format,fields[4],fields[5],fields[6],fields[7],fields[8],fields[9],fields[10],fields[11],fields[12],fields[13],fields[14],fields[15],fields[16],fields[17],fields[18],fields[19],fields[20],fields[21]));
                i = true;
            }
        }
    }
        result.setText(rsl.toString());
        in.close();
        return i;
    }
```

The search is working, but in order to work I must every time put two variables,
but I want to be free (meaning to work with 1 or 2 or more search variables).

So if a line has this (1 ,2 or more) variables inside to display them...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please consider reading through [mcve]

Comment: When doing `in.nextLine()` inside the loop, you should do `while (in.hasNextLine())`, not `in.hasNext()`.

Comment: im asking a solution so i can use 1 or more variables to search on txt file... Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want to check for all items in `search1`, you could create a function that does the check using a `for` loop:

```
public static boolean containsOneOrMore(String text, String[] search) {
    for (String s : search) {
        if (!text.contains(s)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And than in the if becomes:

```
if (containsOneOrMore(line, search1)) {
```

Comment: this solution is perfect but also i want if input is empty to show me all lines

Comment: Also is not display and the other lines if both of variables is contained... only print the first one that finds... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add this method

```
private boolean containsAll(String line, String... matchers)
    {
            for (String matcher : matchers)
            {
                    if (!line.contains(matcher))
                    {
                            return false;
                    }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

And then use

```
if (containsAll(line, search1[0], search1[1])
```